# Getting Active Autonomous Transaction Error even commited explicitly inside the procedure

Tags: oracle, exception, plsql, pragma

I am using pragama Autonomous transaction in procedure to update particular table. And I put commit also in that procedure. But I am getting ora error -06519 Active Autonomous transaction detected and rolled back.

The process inside the Autonomous transaction is updating one account as active status 1 and updating rest all pool accounts active ideal as status 0. End of the update put ai put commit. After updating it returns the main transaction. For debit from active account.

Note: The problem is it runs smoothly. But when it comes to the huge transaction at same second it raises this error.

Example the error raises while 80 - 100 transactions at one second.

its banking IMPS transaction. So the volume is high.

code:

```
Create or replace procedure
ClI_NPCI_FUNDTRANSFER
(in parameters) As
Declare
Variables
Begin
Select statements.

Insert statement

--calling the procedure which has Autonomous transaction

CLI_UPD_POOLACCOUNT(IN PARAMETER) --LINE NO 207

Insert statement

Update statement
End;
```

Procedure of Autonomous Transaction

```
Create or replace procedure
CLI_UPD_POOLACCOUNT
(Parameter in ,
Parameter out
)
As
Begin

Update statement;

Commit;

End; --line 92
```

The error message i got is active Autonomous detected and rolledback 
CLI_UPD_POOLACCOUNT at line 92 and ClI_NPCI_FUNDTRANSFER at line 207..

Comment: Can you provide us your complete code please ?

Comment: Why do you use autonomous transaction at all? Why don't you put CLI_UPD_POOLCACCOUNT code into ClI_NPCI_FUNDTRANSFER and avoid this problem?

Comment: your example does not show any pragma.  Please edit your code and post a [mcve]